# How to find out if a field's values for a given item are only increasing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

For this problem, I'm using Access as a front end for SQL Server, and calling Access through Excel VBA, although I can use a direct ADO connection if there are some T-SQL specific functions that would be more useful here.

I have a table that logs state changes for a set of items, e.g.:

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| docID | state |    date    |
+-------+-------+------------+
|   103 |     5 | 10/15/2013 |
|   103 |     6 | 10/18/2013 |
|   102 |     3 | 10/22/2013 |
|   103 |     2 | 11/1/2013  |
|   102 |     7 | 11/8/2013  |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

For each unique `docID`, I want to figure out whether its state is only increasing from first date to last date, or if it ever decreases.  In the above data set, 103 decreases and 102 only increases.  We can assume that the entries will be in date order.

One way to find this would be to create an object for each `docID` and add these objects to a dictionary, loading each state change into a list and checking to see whether the state has decreased, something like this:

```
function isDecreasing(cl as changeList) as boolean

for c=2 to cl.count
 if cl.item(c).state < cl.item(c-1).state then
  isDecreasing=true
  exit function
 end if
next

isDecreasing=false

end function
```

But this will slow my query down a lot because I'll have to convert all the table data into objects.  It also means I'll have to write a lot of additional code to create and manage the objects for calculating and generating reports.

Is there any way to write a query in SQL Server or Access that can perform the same type of analysis on the whole data set?

Comment: For your problem, a VB loop on ADODB.Recordset may be more efficient than A COMPLEX SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem using Access-only functionality.  But, if you have SQL Server 2012, you can use `lead()`/`lag()` functionality.  There is another way, just using `row_number()`, which is available since SQL Server 2005.

Here is the idea.  Enumerate the rows within each `docId` first by `state` and also by `date`.  If the enumerations are the same, then the sequence is non-decreasing (essentially increasing).  If different, then there is a bump in the road.  Here is the code:

```
select docid,
       (case when sum(case when rn_ds <> rn_sd then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 'Increasing'
             else 'Decreasing'
        end) as SequenceType
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by docId order by date, state) as rn_ds,
             row_number() over (partition by docId order by state, date) as rn_sd
      from d
     ) d
group by docid;
```

Note that I've made the sort a little more complicated by using both fields.  This handles the case when two dates in a row have the same state (probably not allowed, but might as well make the technique more stable).

Answer (score 2):

In his otherwise excellent answer, Gordon Linoff said:

> You have a problem using Access-only functionality

Really?

For the given data, which I've put in a table called [StateChanges]:

```
docID  state  date      
-----  -----  ----------
  103      5  2013-10-15
  103      6  2013-10-18
  102      3  2013-10-22
  103      2  2013-11-01
  102      7  2013-11-08
```

I can create the following saved query in Access named [PreviousDates]

```sql
SELECT t1.docID, t1.date, MAX(t2.date) AS PreviousDate
FROM
    StateChanges t1
    INNER JOIN
    StateChanges t2
        ON t2.docID = t1.docID
            AND t2.date < t1.date
GROUP BY t1.docID, t1.date
```

It returns

```
docID  date        PreviousDate
-----  ----------  ------------
  102  2013-11-08  2013-10-22  
  103  2013-10-18  2013-10-15  
  103  2013-11-01  2013-10-18
```

Then I can use the following query to identify the [docID]'s where the [state] went down

```sql
SELECT curr.docID
FROM
    (
        PreviousDates pd
        INNER JOIN
        StateChanges curr
            ON curr.date = pd.date
    )
    INNER JOIN
    StateChanges prev
        ON prev.date = pd.PreviousDate
WHERE curr.state < prev.state
```

It returns

```
docID
-----
  103
```

In fact, both queries are so simple that we can combine them into a single query that does the whole thing in one shot:

```sql
SELECT curr.docID
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT t1.docID, t1.date, MAX(t2.date) AS PreviousDate
            FROM
                StateChanges t1
                INNER JOIN
                StateChanges t2
                    ON t2.docID = t1.docID
                        AND t2.date < t1.date
            GROUP BY t1.docID, t1.date
        ) PreviousDates
        INNER JOIN
        StateChanges curr
            ON curr.date = PreviousDates.date
    )
    INNER JOIN
    StateChanges prev
        ON prev.date = PreviousDates.PreviousDate
WHERE curr.state < prev.state
```

So where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> For each unique docID, I want to figure out whether its state is only increasing from first date to last date, or if it ever decreases.

So what you want to know is, for a given record a, does there `exist` a record `b` where the date of `a` is earlier but the state of `b` is lower.

So just ask that.

```
select docID 
from T a 
where 
exists (
    select 1 from T b where b.date > a.date and b.state < a.state
)
```